# How can I remove <div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div> from the body?

Tags: angular, dom, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, angular-renderer2

I want to remove an opened modal on a page but I could not access to this div element that lock the document,

I could not access to this div, to define an ID or Name to remove it by Renderer2,

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
```

something like this,

```
this.renderer.removeChild(document.body, HTMLDivElement);
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you want to avoid direct DOM manipulation in Angular at all costs. How is this modal opened in the first place? Can the parent component use `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to remove it would be the use of *ngIf. It adds and removes DOM elements with condition.

For example

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="foo" class="modal-backdrop fade show">
  I will be added to the DOM only if foo is true
</div>
```

Typescript

```
someMethod(value){
  this.foo=value // or this.foo=!this.foo
}
```

where someMethod() is where your  `this.renderer.removeChild(...` lies.